# getting abrupt height for a horizontal recyclerview lists

Tags: android

I am creating a horizontal `recyclerView` containing `cardView` which in turn have a list of information.
If a name is of more than 3 lines the overall height of the recyclerview is disturbed.

Let me explain with the example:

**Below is the normal layout when no text is more than 1**

[image] line

**Now below is the layout when there is more than 1 line**

[image]

Below are all the relevant files that are used

**single_cast_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_dimen"
        android:elevation="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/castImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/castContentDesc"
                android:focusable="true"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/castName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/castImage"
                android:lines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cast_name_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/cast_name_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/cast_name_padding"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/movieNameBackground"
                android:textSize="@dimen/cast_name_size"
                tools:text="Actor Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/castMovieName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/castName"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cast_name_padding"
                tools:text="character name" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**castListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.ashish.moviesnow.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.ashish.moviesnow.Model.CastDetails;
import com.example.ashish.moviesnow.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;



public class CastListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CastListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<CastDetails> mList;

    public CastListAdapter(Context mContext, List<CastDetails> mList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mList = mList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cast_layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        CastDetails cd = mList.get(position);
        String replacedString = cd.getmCastMovieName().replace("/","/\n");
        if (cd.getmCastMovieName().length()>20){

        }
        holder.mCastText.setText(cd.getmCastRealName());
        holder.mCastMovieName.setText(replacedString);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(cd.getmCastPoster())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .into(holder.mCastImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mCastText,mCastMovieName;
        private ImageView mCastImage;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mCastText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.castName);
            mCastImage=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.castImage);
            mCastMovieName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.castMovieName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want , to show only one line or any else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:ellipsize = "end"` so if the sentence size larger than your line it will show dots (...) at the end you can also show it as you want.

Use `android:lines="2"` and `android:ellipsize = "end"` it will be fine for you . Or increase `android:lines="3"` and fix the `layout_height` as it. So all the layouts row will be show as same height.

```
 <TextView
   ....
   android:text="Hi I am Abhishek, How are you ?"
   android:ellipsize = "end"  
 />
```

**Output will be as below :**

```
Hi I am Abhi.....
```

**Start's output will be :** ...am Abhishek

**End's output will be :** Hi I am Ab...

**Middle's output will be :** Hi...Abhishek